# Write $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_{15}$ as direct product of two cyclic groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Consider the finite Abelian group $G = \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_{15}$. Find an isomorphic group a $G$ which is the direct product of only two cyclic groups. From this it can be deduced that $G$ can be generated by two elements. Give an example of such elements.

I suppose the order of $G$ is $360$, but I don't find two cyclic groups whose direct product makes $360$, I find: $360= 2^3 \times 5 \times 3^2$, but it's: $\mathbb Z _{24} \times \mathbb Z _{15}$, but only $15$ is cyclic...

Comment: This is a special case of the chinese remainder theorem. Note that $2$ and $15$ are coprime so that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, but $\mathbb Z$ /30 $\mathbb Z$ isn't cyclic, so I can't use 30 and 12... @Mummytheturkey

Comment: It is generated by $\overline 1 = 30\mathbb Z + 1$, so it is cyclic.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is always cyclic. The reason the choice you make in your quesiton is wrong is that $12$ and $2$ are not coprime, and so $\mathbb{Z}/12 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/24$

Comment: so if I use the 30 and 12 is correct? @Mummytheturkey

Comment: For the example I can use $\mathbb Z _{2} \times \mathbb Z _{180}$?

Comment: No, since $12$ and $15$ are not coprime.

Comment: Okkay, maybe I finally understood, I can only use 2 and 180 or 3 and 120 @Shaun

Comment: Again, no; $3$ and $120$ do not work for the same reason $2$ and $180$ don't.

Comment: And with 5 and 72? I'm sorry but I can't really find a combination @Shaun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\gcd(2,15)=1$, we have, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, that $$\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_{15}\cong\Bbb Z_{30},$$ which is cyclic; hence a group isomorphic to $G$ would be $$\Bbb Z_{12}\times \Bbb Z_{30}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, @AlbanoPitagorico!

Comment: Don't forget, @AlbanoPitagorico, that you can earn points for both of us by "accepting" the answer by clicking  the check mark $\checkmark$.